# Issue with replacing value if cell is empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

In my spreadsheet on Google Apps I have multiple columns: first is `row[0]` for check-in date, second is `row[1]` for check-out date … and so on up to `row[17]`. My function is purposed to send confirmations for newly registered reservations, which is determined by the *reservation status column* (`row[16]`) and if the value contained in a cell is `Новое бронирование` than the function sends a notification to a front-desk manager (but if value is a different one then it does nothing excepting a check of column cells' values).

The problem is that I fail to modify my function to send *reservationNotes* (`row[11]`) if and only if a cell in a corresponding row (i.e. with a new reservation) contains reservation notes itself: the cell value in `row[11]` should be *not empty*.

Here is the source code:

```
/* Отправка уведомлений о добавлении новых бронирований (т.е., новых строк в таблице на активном листе). */
function NotifyManagerOfNewReservation() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // Строка с первым бронированием для начала обработки.
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Количество строк с бронированиями для обработки.
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 18); // Охват столбцов для обработки ячеек, в данном случае с 1-го по 18-ый.
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Получить значение ячеек в каждой ячейке каждой строке в рамках столбцов, охваченных верхним кодом.
    var statusNewReservation = "Новое бронирование";
    var statusNotificationSent = "Уведомление отправлено";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var checkInDate = new Date(row[0]);
        var checkOutDate = new Date(row[1]);
        var formattedCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var fullCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 14:00";
        var fullCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 12:00";
        var reservationNumber = [i+2] + "0" + checkInDate.getFullYear(); // С 18:35, 26.09.2016 (МСК) используется универсальный формат номера бронирований (до этого момента он формировался по формуле [i+2]).
        var roomType = "«" + row[2] + "»";
        var numberOfGuests = row[3];
        var numberOfNights = Math.round(Math.abs((checkOutDate.getTime() - checkInDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
        var costPerNight = row[4];
        var prepaymentCost = row[8];
        var unpaidCost = (costPerNight*numberOfNights)-prepaymentCost;
        var formattedNumberOfNights = numberOfNights + " ночей"; // Количество ночей проживания.
        var formattedCostPerNight = costPerNight + " руб.";
        var formattedPrepaymentCost = prepaymentCost + " руб.";
        var formattedUnpaidCost = unpaidCost + " руб."; // Сумма, которую необходимо оплатить гостю по приезде.
        var contactFullName = row[5];
        var contactPhone = row[6];
        var contactEmail = row[7];
        var reservationNotes = row[11];
        var fullReservationNotes = "";
        var notificationStatus = row[16]; // Столбец, в котором выставляется статус отправки/неотправки уведомлений о новых бронированиях.
        var reservationsListLink = "https://www.berdyanskaya56.ru/intranet/reservations/";
        /* Установка параметров отправителя. */
        var senderAliases = GmailApp.getAliases(); // Запрашиваем список всех элиасов электропочтового аккаунта.
        Logger.log(senderAliases); // Проверяем список электропочтовых эллиасов и выбираем требующийся в формате senderAliases[N], где алиас, идущий первым по порядку, имеет значение «0» (к примеру, senderAliases[0] для ruslanseletskiy@gmail.com).
        var senderAddress = "ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru"; // Указываем выбранный алиас.
        var senderName = "Робот Руслана (мини-гостиница «Бердянская 56»)"; // Уточняем имя отправителя.
        var replyTo = "ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru"; // Указываем электропочтовый адрес для ответа.
        var highriseDropbox = "dropbox@18407830.minihotelberdyanskaya56.highrisehq.com"; // Адрес общего ящика аккаунта ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru в Хайрайзе.
        var bccAddress = highriseDropbox;
        var managerEmail = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru"; // Электропочта менеджера фронт-офиса.
        var subject = "Новое бронирование № " + reservationNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")";
        /* Не показываем строку с примечаниями к бронированию в случае их отсутствия. */
        if (reservationNotes !== "") {fullReservationNotes == "\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n"}
        var message = "Добавлено бронирование № " + reservationNumber + "!" + "\n" + "\nДанные нового бронирования:" + "\n" + "\nЗаезд: " + fullCheckInDate + "\nВыезд: " + fullCheckOutDate + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\n" + "\nКоличество ночей: " + formattedNumberOfNights + "\nЦена за ночь: " + formattedCostPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + formattedPrepaymentCost + "\n(" + formattedCostPerNight + " × " + formattedNumberOfNights + ")" + " – " + formattedPrepaymentCost + " = " + formattedUnpaidCost + " к оплате" + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + contactFullName + "\nМобильный телефон: " + contactPhone + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + contactEmail + "\n" + fullReservationNotes + "\nПожалуйста, срочно сделай занятым номер " + roomType + " в период с " + formattedCheckInDate + " (с 14:00)" + " по " + formattedCheckOutDate + " (до 12:00)" + " в экселевском файле!" + "\n" + "\n* Посмотреть полный список бронирований всегда можно тут: " + reservationsListLink + ".";  
            if (notificationStatus == statusNewReservation) { // Условное выражение, позволяющее не отправлять письма о тех же бронировациях повторно.
            // MailApp.sendEmail(managerEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
            GmailApp.sendEmail(managerEmail, subject, message, {from: senderAddress, name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo, bcc: bccAddress});
            sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 17).setValue(statusNotificationSent);
            Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о новом бронировании № " + reservationNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + managerEmail + ".");
            }
            SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Показываем пользователю что изменения вступают в силу.
       }
}
```

I use an "indirect" variable `fullReservationNotes` to check `if (reservationNotes !== "") {fullReservationNotes == "\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n"}` for implementing this but it doesn't work properly: it shows none of reservations notes even if a cell in a `reservationNotes` (`row[11]`) column is filled or if it is empty.

Thus, if cell in `row[11]` is empty for any added reservation then there should be *nothing put* in `"\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n"` and `fullReservationNotes` is also should be left empty in a notification message.

I've also spent a half of an hour on searching existing questions but I didn't find any similar cases to my own.

How can fix this issue? Maybe I miss anything with a loop above described if clause?

Thanks a lot you for all your contributions in solving this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, I believe the problem is with your assignment after the if, you are using the comparison operator (==) instead of the assignment operator (=)

Try:

```
if (reservationNotes !== "") {fullReservationNotes = "\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problems I see with your code is that there is no semi-colon at the end of full reservationNotes assignment and also I don't think == is an assignment operator.

```
if (reservationNotes !== "") 
{
   fullReservationNotes == "\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n"
}
```